# Intel Xdk Back Button - Not working

Tags: jquery, device, intel, back-button

I'm trying to handle the back button in intel xdk. But I've tried almost everything in stackOverflow and none of them work for me!

I'm working with panels hidden or not! Maybe that is the problem, really I'm trying to not work with the appFramework, and build my own, with just jquery.. THe application works fine just the back button is not working!

Someone have the magic for this?

This is my code.

```
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/mapa.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // This event handler is fired once the intel libraries are ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //hide splash screen now that our app is ready to run
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ui.launch();
        }, 50);
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
    //initial event handler to detect when intel is ready to roll
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
<script src="js/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ui.autoLaunch = false;
    $.ui.useOSThemes = false; //Change this to false to force a device theme
    $.ui.blockPageScroll();
    $.ui.goBack();
    //$.ui.showBackButton=false;
    $(document).ready(function () {

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login" class="">
    <div class="centralizaImg">
        <a onclick="logar();"><img src="imagens/lg_face.gif"/></a>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="layout" class="naoLogado">
  <div id="header">
      <div class="backHome"><a href="#home" class="icon home"></a></div>
      <h1>Move</h1>
    </div>
  <div id="content">
      <div id="home" class="panel ativo(this is active)" title="Move">
      </div>

      <div id="poi" class="panel" title="Pontos">
        </div>

        <div id="historico" class="panel" title="Histórico">
          </div>

          <div id="map" class="panel" title="Mapa">
            <div id="map_canvas" class="escondido"></div>
              <a class="buttonGetLocal icon location" onclick="getLocal();"></a>
           </div>
  </div>
 <div id="navbar">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#poi"><i class="icon pin"></i><span>Pontos Turísticos</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#historico"><i class="icon star"></i><span>Histórico</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#map"><i class="icon settings"></i><span>Configurações</span></a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div><!-- fim layout -->
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //On Click Event
   $("#navbar a, #header a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ancora = $(this).attr('href');
        var idPainel = ancora.substr(1, ancora.length);
        if(idPainel === "map"){
            $("#map_canvas").removeClass("escondido").addClass("ativo");
            map();
        }
        $(".panel").removeClass("ativo").fadeOut("fast");
        var titulo = $('#'+idPainel).attr('title');
        $("#header h1").html(titulo);
        $('#'+idPainel).slideToggle(600);
    });
});
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    if(document.getElementById('#home')){
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
        navigator.app.backHistory();
        history.go(-1);
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That back button is an App Framework back button, not the hardware back button. See the XDK docs (http://www.intel.com/software/xdkdocs) for intro regarding how to build a hybrid mobile app. In general, you need to put anything that depends on device-specific features (like the hardware back button) into the device ready code segment, otherwise you won't have access to device features (the native code needs to initialize).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at creating a project using templates  and for reviewing how back button works try the ListView template. The back button is not the hardware back button in the bottom of the device.

Here are types of projects you can create with the XDK.
http://hodentekmobile.blogspot.com/2014/08/creating-projects-with-intel-xdk-part-2.html